# return all paths in a nested dictionary that also contains a list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, path, nested

First of all, I apologize for my poor English, I hope this question has been clearly stated.

I need a function that, when I call it, returns all possible paths of a nested dictionary that includes a list.

Example :

Input variable:

```
var={"a":"b","c":["d","e",{"f":"","h":["i",{"j":"q"} ]}],"m":"","n":["d","e",{"b":"","c":"","f":"r"}]," r":"r","k":["d","t","h"]}
```

The output should look like this:

```
a/b 
c/d 
c/e 
c/f/ 
c/h/i 
c/h/j/q 
m/
n/d
n/e
n/b/
n/c/
n/f/r 
r/r 
k/d 
k/t 
k/h
```

Notes :

It doesn't matter if the lines are printed in the order of the lines above, but the values of the lines must be the same as the lines above . Each path starts with the key of the outermost dictionary and ends when it can no longer be continued, that is, for example, we reach a dictionary value that is not a dictionary or a list, or we reach an item from a list, but if we reach a list or a dictionary, for example The path must continue

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: This is a simple recursive algorithm.

Comment: I found a few lines of code on the internet and changed them a bit, but none of them were good and there were some bugs, so to avoid more confusion, I didn't put any code here because it's not helpful (because it wasn't my code and I didn't know much about it, but all They include recursive functions and all of them are written for nested dictionaries, but dictionaries that only contain the dictionary inside them and do not include a list.)

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_paths(d, path=''):
    paths = []
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            paths.extend(get_paths(value, path + key + "/"))
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for i, item in enumerate(value):
                if isinstance(item, dict) or isinstance(item, list):
                    paths.extend(get_paths(item, path + key + "/"))
                else:
                    paths.append(path + key + "/" + str(item))
        else:
            paths.append(path + key + "/" + str(value) if value else path + key + "/")
    return paths

var={"a":"b","c":["d","e",{"f":"","h":["i",{"j":"q"} ]}],"m":"","n":["d","e",{"b":"","c":"","f":"r"}]," r":"r","k":["d","t","h"]} 


paths = get_paths(var)
for path in paths:
    print(path)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, the code works correctly

Comment: @AEPHello. I'm happy to hear that it helped u